# It's not showing full content for posts pages in wordpress "[...]" while customing some changes in the style.css file

Tags: php, css

I am new to wordpress.I was trying to do some changes in the style.css file but something wrong I did due to which the content for all the posts in the site it start showing "[...]" after a small content that too not in formatted form but simple.I don't know were I did wrong while customing site.And why it's showing theme name
Will be very great full for any find of help[image]

Comment: This is exactly why it is unwise to mess with the `style.css` file. Also, when the theme gets updated, your changes will be lost. Learn how to make a child theme. It's very easy.

Comment: This is more a theme-specific question than a WordPress question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme name is showing in the post image because, I'm guessing, you haven't uploaded a featured image for that post and it's therefore displaying a placeholder image instead.

The post text (excerpt) is showing shortened due to a theme setting or how the theme intends it to look and nothing at all to do with your `style.css` file. Or, if you've customised any other theme files such as `single.php` you may have changed `the_content()` function to `the_excerpt()` which is causing the shortened text.

However, as @cjbj states, you should not make changes to the parent themes CSS files or any of the other theme files. Any customisations should be done using a child theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

It might benefit you to also read the theme documentation.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Can you click on the tick next to my answer to accept it please?